# How to install this kernel module to use IpTables in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: kernel, 19.04, iptables

So, I am studying IpTables using Ubuntu 19.04 - kernel 5.0.0-32-generic. Following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldB8kDEtTZA, I have to load the following kernel modules:

> x_tables, ip_tables, iptable_filter, xt_tcpudp, nf_conntrack,
>   xt_state, nf_conntrack_ipv4

The only one not loaded, because it wasn't found in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/` was the `nf_conntrack_ipv4`.

My questions are: How do I install/load this module? Do kernel modules become obsolete in new kernels?

Comment: same problem with "nf_nat_masquerade" module https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198314/how-to-load-nf-conntrack-and-nf-nat-masquerade-modules-in-kernel-hwe

Answer (score 0):

Based on that [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/charm-neutron-openvswitch/+bug/1834213) on Launchpad :

Do this following command :

```
sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

you can verify that `nf_conntrack_ipv4` mod is loaded by doing this command :

```
lsmod | grep nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that already and as I said, it returns it wans't found in /lib/modules/$(uname -r). I guess I have to load it manually and need to know how.

Comment: so you have an error like that `modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ipv4 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-32-generic
` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the error I get since this module doesn't seem to be in my computer nor in the `/lib/modules/5.0.0-32-generic/modules.dep` file, I think.

Comment: probably you can continue your tutorial even by skipping load of `nf_conntrack_ipv4`, you had load `nf_conntrack` (possible that `nf_conntrack_ipv4` were removed on modern Ubuntu, because of ipv6)

Comment: @damadam what about nf_nat_masquerade? has it also been "removed in modern versions of ubuntu"? (no sense)

Comment: @ajcg I'm not the specialist, so I can't help you about `nf_nat_masquerade`