# How to load nf_conntrack and nf_nat_masquerade modules in kernel HWE?

Tags: kernel, iptables

I have some iptables rules that require the **nf_conntrack** and **nf_nat_masquerade** modules, however these are not available in the [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) kernel (Ubuntu 18.04.3 x64).

Note: They are only available in previous kernels (example: 4.15.0-70-generic, etc)

```
ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/*/netfilter/
```

[actual HWE kernel 5.0.0.-37-generic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd7bc.png)

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_nat_masquerade not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic
modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic
modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ipv4 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic
```

How can I install/activate/load this modules for this kernel with modprobe?

PD: responding to the user's suggestion

```
grep NF_NAT_MASQ /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_NF_NAT_MASQUERADE_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_MASQUERADE_IPV6=y
```

but the modules do not appear as "loaded" with this command:

```
cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches
```

Comment: I think they are already included in kernel, you can check output of 

`grep NF_NAT_MASQ /boot/config-$(uname -r)`

see the explain in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126622/

Comment: Similar question without solution (possible bug)  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183231/how-to-install-this-kernel-module-to-use-iptables-in-ubuntu-19-04

Comment: @alfred Thanks. You are right, but If they are already included, why does the error come out? And why don't they appear loaded when I run the cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches command?

Comment: Any respond `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-37-generic` ?

Comment: @nobody ii  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-37-generic   5.0.0-37.40~18.04.1                                      amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

Comment: @pcr never mind. Can confirm it for disco too.

Comment: @pcr Oh, I've seen the launchpad bug.